# How to perform multiplication in an sql select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

How i can write sql query to calculate annual salary(12 times monthly salary) from this table for each row ?

```
id | msalary
01 | 323
02 | 5126
03 | NULL
04 | 2187
05 | NULL
```

output

```
id | msalary |msalary*12 
01 | 323     |?
02 | 5126    |?
03 | NULL    |?
04 | 2187    |?
05 | NULL    |?
```

How i can find Sum of all annual salary by excluding null values ?

Comment: What does that mean? What should the output be? What did you try?

Comment: Are you going to replace the `?` with actual values?

Comment: yes .i want to calculate the values of annual salary for each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is employee... this will give you what you want.

`select id, msalary, 12*msalary from employee`

If you want to count the sum of yearly salary this should suffice...

`select sum(12*msalary) from employee;`

NULL values will be automatically ignored.

Comment: what to do for null values ?

Comment: it depends on your requirement. As of now, 12*NULL will result into NULL again it may depend on database